# how to use xlsx writer anotation work in python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have so much data with much column in excel and i want to do some merge formatting using xlsx writer through python using anotation in the documentation here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html

This is my code :

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['report']

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter'
})

rows, columns = data_pdam.shape

# the problem
for col in range(len(data.columns)):
    worksheet.merge_range(1, col, 1, col+2, 'name', merge_format)
```

This is my data look like:

```
X      Y      Z      AA      AB       AC
value         value          value     
1      6      3      4       3        5
2      3      4      5       6        2
```

I want to merge each value header to be 2 column
The problem is column Z and AA to the end of data column not merging
How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to iterate with `(2n, 2n+1)` for the column numbers. Something like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC']

merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'border': 1
})

for index, name in enumerate(columns):
    worksheet.merge_range(1, 2 * index, 1, 2 * index + 1, name, merge_format)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]